Google Form Responses Export to XML file
all.  I trying to export a google form as an XML file as described in this OLD post: Map or Export Google Form Responses to PDF Form Fields
I followed the steps but the script keeps erroring. I'm hoping someone with actual scripting experience can help me fix it.  I'll post my code as its outlined in the linked STACK.
The formXml.html
<fields xmlns:xfdf="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf-transition/">
<TMR><? dataTMR ?></TMR>
<Date><? dataDate ?></Date>
<Time><? dataTime ?></Time>
</fields>

The Code.gs
function formSubmission(eventData) {
// Get a handle on the xml template
var formXml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('formXml');

// Replace template values with user input
formXml.dataTMR = eventData.namedValues['TMR'];
formXml.dataDate = eventData.namedValues['Date'];
formXml.dataTime = eventData.namedValues['Time'];

// Evaluate the template with substitutions
var xml = formXml.evaluate();

// Get the evaluated template as text, prepend the XML Declaration
var formXmlText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + xml.getContent();

// Save user input as XML file on Google Drive
var fileName = 'Form ' + eventData.namedValues['Timestamp'];
var xmlFile = DriveApp.createFile(fileName, formXmlText, MimeType.XML);
}

Here's the execution log:
enter image description here
I would appreciate any help I can get.
I've copied the steps as closely as I can without having any real scripting background.
Here is a screenshot of the code.gs. I understand that the colors of objects might help indicate problems.
Code.gs inside the Script Editor

About your current issue, did you run your function formSubmission with the event object eventData? If you cannot understand this, can I ask you about the detailed flow for executing your function formSubmission?

The function is executed using a trigger on form submission. Does that answer the question?

Thank you for replying. In that case, where is your showing script? It's in the container-bound script of Google Form or Google Spreadsheet or the standalone script?

I did the scripting in the google sheet.

I've added a screenshot of the actual code.gs inside script editor as I understand the color of object sometimes helps troubleshoot.

I reproduced the app script in the form as well and the same issue occurs.

Here is a link to the PDF. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I1L3zR8ltgkA9YEOWoI9AjI4cw-KgdMF/view?usp=sharing

The adobe stuff isn't the problem. The problem is the google app script not generating the xml file. that's why I'm only using a few of the fields for the testing above.

Try changing these:
formXml.dataTMR = eventData.namedValues['TMR'];
formXml.dataDate = eventData.namedValues['Date'];
formXml.dataTime = eventData.namedValues['Time'];

to this:
formXml.dataTMR = eventData.namedValues['TMR'][0];
formXml.dataDate = eventData.namedValues['Date'][0];
formXml.dataTime = eventData.namedValues['Time'][0];


That didn't seem to help.

Well I just noticed the error but I never use xml.  What do you use it for?

I'm going to use the xml to import into an adobe fillable form.
